# How can I fix turkish character on font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am using chunk five fonts on my web site as font-face on css.When I use pure fonts on photoshop, there will turkish characters exist.But when I convert it to font-face.I won't display Turkish characters.I shared a screenshot on the following segment of text;
[image]

I've tried to convert different type of font faces.I tried to convert it with the subsetting support and I've checked **Turkish** field on it.Also, I entered **ş,Ş,İ,ı,ğ,Ğ,ü,Ü,Ç,ç,Ö,ö** Single Characters field on converter.Unfortunately,It's not worked for me.How can I fix that problem?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: did you convert your font for web use and used font-path correctly??

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/turkish

Comment: Yep, everythink is ok.I checked it from google.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the actual font data, CSS, and HTML. Can you set up a jsfiddle or other example page with a minimal example that we can view?

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert fonts from another sources and will fix. I know this is old post but maybe helps you.

Some sources:

http://convertfonts.com/

https://www.web-font-generator.com/

http://www.flaticon.com/font-face

https://fontie.flowyapps.com/home

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the exact same problem as you when dealing with font conversions for Turkish. First, I had run a conversion using FontSquirrel's tool ([available here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)), but it turns out the conversion was stripping these much-needed characters for the Turkish language.

One of the references from @Karmacoma's answer was very interesting and did the trick for me ([Fontie](https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator)) because it delivers advanced options, which gives us more control over the conversion process.

In order to cover the special characters in Turkish, you must use `Switch to advanced view` and run the conversion with `Latin Extended-A`.

[image]

I went to Wikipedia for a list of characters covered in Latin Extended-A and [you can find them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A).